# SQL adding Months

Tags: mysql, addition, time-series

Hello I am trying to get records of certain months. For example for this query I would want the user to see the current month which is "May" and one month from the past which would be "April". I don't want my query to run any other month from that point on. I am stuck with this query and cant figure it out. Basically I need a function in my query to automatically know this month and the 1 month before to show the records. Thank you

```
DECLARE @Year int
set @Year = 2014
SELECT d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone

   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Feburary
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November
   , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December
   , COUNT(*) 'Year to Date'
   FROM tdealer a 
   JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
   JOIN tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
   JOIN tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
  where YEAR (c.Funded_date) = @Year
  GROUP BY d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone
```

Comment: Check out [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) with %M parameter!

Comment: The [date and time functions of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) can give you the current month and of course you can subtract a month and get the last one. Where are you stuck?

Comment: You should be able to use something like `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(c.Funded_date, '%Y%m') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH), '%Y%m') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')` in your query to get the details for the current and previous month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to do two things:

1. Create an expression which converts any arbitrary `DATETIME` into the first day of the month in which that date occurred.
2. Use it appropriately in `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

The expression is

```
DATE_FORMAT(whatever, '%Y-%m-01')
```

This takes, for example '2014-05-28 12:22:30', and turns it into '2014-05-01'. It's really handy to convert one valid `DATE` to another valid `DATE`, because then you can use all the good date arithmetic built into MySQL.

So, for example, if you want the first of the month before the present month you use this:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Here's the outline of your query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(c.Funded_date, '%Y-%m-01') AS month_beginning,
       d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone,
       COUNT(1) AS itemcount
  FROM tdealer a 
  JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
  JOIN tContract c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id 
  JOIN tCompany d ON c.company_id = d.company_id
 where c.Funded_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND c.Funded_date <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.Funded_date, '%Y-%m-01'),
          d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone
 ORDER BY d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone,
          DATE_FORMAT(c.Funded_date, '%Y-%m-01')
```

See how you choose the two-month period? It starts with the first day of the month before the present month, and ends with the first day of next month, but without including that day.

How to do this sort of thing is written up at http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/